# How do you add one to another integer when it satisfies an if statement?

Tags: java, int

I want my code to document thes a day of the month like the 1st of each month and then put it into a integer for the day of the week the 1st of the month was on.

Eg.

Wednesday is the first of the month in July, so Wednesday would have + 1 for the number of times it was the first of the month.

Monday : 0
Tuesday : 0
Wednesday : 1

but i cant figure out how i would code that in java.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is really asking.  You want to add one to a variable if a given condition is satisfied?  Are you just asking how an if statement works?  This is the syntax to add one to a variable under a certain condition, if that helps: `if (condition) { variable++; }`.

Comment: Some languages (e.g. C) use the convention that a condition is 1 if true, 0 if false. So you could say `x + (x % 3 == 2)`, for instance.

Comment: Are you really asking "How do I determine the day of the week for a given date?"

Comment: @vonbrand Yes, but Java isn't one of these languages.

Answer (score 2):

Java offers the classes you need, [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html), [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html), and [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html).

Determine the current year.

```
    ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" );
    Year year = Year.now( z );
```

You can make a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) to track which months have which day of the week as their first day of week. We use [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html) for its extreme efficiency when using an enum as the key.

```
    Map < DayOfWeek, AtomicInteger > map = new EnumMap <>( DayOfWeek.class );
```

Loop all the months of the year. The [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum defines a dozen objects, one for each month of the year. Calling `Month.values` gives an array of all those months, in chronological order.

For each month in the array of months, get the `YearMonth` for that month. Then get the first day of that month, and ask the resulting [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) what day-of-week is that date.

Use that day-of-week, that `DayOfWeek` enum object, as the key to the map. See if an entry is present for that key. If not, make an entry, a new `AtomicInteger` set to zero. Ask again if that `DayOfWeek` enum object is present as a key in our map. We know on the second ask that indeed it must be there, so no need to check for `null`. We increment the count in that `AtomicInteger` by one, to count the `YearMonth` of our loop.

Why [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) class? Because `AtomicInteger` can be incremented, unlike `Integer` which is immutable.

```
    for ( Month month : Month.values() )
    {
        YearMonth yearMonth = year.atMonth( month );
        DayOfWeek dow = yearMonth.atDay( 1 ).getDayOfWeek();
        System.out.println( "yearMonth: " + yearMonth + " = " + yearMonth.atDay( 1 ) + " = " + dow );
        map.putIfAbsent( dow , new AtomicInteger( 0 ) );
        map.get( dow ).incrementAndGet();
    }
```

Dump to console.

```
    System.out.println( "map = " + map );
```

For the year 2020, the result is:

```
yearMonth: 2020-01 = 2020-01-01 = WEDNESDAY
yearMonth: 2020-02 = 2020-02-01 = SATURDAY
yearMonth: 2020-03 = 2020-03-01 = SUNDAY
yearMonth: 2020-04 = 2020-04-01 = WEDNESDAY
yearMonth: 2020-05 = 2020-05-01 = FRIDAY
yearMonth: 2020-06 = 2020-06-01 = MONDAY
yearMonth: 2020-07 = 2020-07-01 = WEDNESDAY
yearMonth: 2020-08 = 2020-08-01 = SATURDAY
yearMonth: 2020-09 = 2020-09-01 = TUESDAY
yearMonth: 2020-10 = 2020-10-01 = THURSDAY
yearMonth: 2020-11 = 2020-11-01 = SUNDAY
yearMonth: 2020-12 = 2020-12-01 = TUESDAY
map = {MONDAY=1, TUESDAY=2, WEDNESDAY=3, THURSDAY=1, FRIDAY=1, SATURDAY=2, SUNDAY=2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array to hold the values, following a convention that makes sense to you (Monday is element 0 or Sunday is element 0). In Java, Sunday is typically stored as element 0 in the time utility, so you can use this convention to get an integer index for the day of the week and increment that index if it appears as the first for your date argument.

The below example will get you started with a code to check if today's date is the first of the month, incrementing the array if it is. Note today is not the 1st, which I used in my example.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Test {
    //Check if day is the 1st of the month
    static boolean isFirstofMonth;
    private boolean isFirstDayofMonth() {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        int dayOfMonth = today.getDayOfMonth();
        if(dayOfMonth == 1) {
            return isFirstofMonth = true;
        }
        else {
            return isFirstofMonth = false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Build ArrayList with values (NOTE int values default to 0)
        int[] Days = new int[7];
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        int val = today.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
        //Use today as argument
        Test t = new Test();
        t.isFirstDayofMonth();
        //Increment at the appropriate index in the array if it's the first
        if(t.isFirstDayofMonth()) {
            Days[val] += 1;
        }
        else {
            
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Days));
        }
    }
```

Not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can easily modify this if you are seeking to use a different argument. To then print in your desired format, you could then do something like this:

```
String[] week = new String[] {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

for(int i = 0; i < week.length; i ++) {
    System.out.println(week(i) + ":" + Days(i)
}
```

Encourage you to try it out yourself a bit! :)

Comment: It’s a good idea to use library methods. The `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated, so far from the best choice. Java knows the names of the days of the week (even in many languages), so don’t hardcode them yourself, use library methods for those too.

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), `GregorianCalendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: Points taken. I've updated it to use java.time instead

Comment: One of your methods is using java.time, the other is still using `Calendar`, so they don’t work together. On one hand a step in the right direction, on the other a mess, sorry.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah that's my bad. Must've missed some of my code when I copy-pasted it in last time. Should be correct now!